# Powershell: trying to find enabled users with no expired passwords

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In Powershell, I'm trying to list all Active Directory user accounts that are enabled and their passwords have not expired.

I get the same results whether I select 'True' or 'False' in the below commands:

Search for **False**:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties * -ResultSetSize 10 | where { $_.PasswordExpired -eq "False" } | select-object displayname, emailaddress, passwordexpired | Sort-Object displayname


|displayname|emailaddress|passwordexpired|
|-----------|------------|---------------|
|user1||True|
|user2|user1@somedomain.com|True|
|user3|user2@somedomain.com|True|
|user4|user3@somedomain.com|True|
|user5|user4@somedomain.com|True|
```

Search for **True**:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties * -ResultSetSize 10 | where { $_.PasswordExpired -eq "True" } | select-object displayname, emailaddress, passwordexpired | Sort-Object displayname


|displayname|emailaddress|passwordexpired|
|-----------|------------|---------------|
|user1||True|
|user2|user1@somedomain.com|True|
|user3|user2@somedomain.com|True|
|user4|user3@somedomain.com|True|
|user5|user4@somedomain.com|True|
```

Another variation I tried:

```
get-aduser -filter { enabled -eq $true } -properties * -resultsetsize 10 | where {$_.PasswordExpired -eq "False"} | select-object displayname, emailaddress, passwordexpired | Sort-Object displayname


|displayname|emailaddress|passwordexpired|
|-----------|------------|---------------|
|user1||True|
|user2|user1@somedomain.com|True|
|user3|user2@somedomain.com|True|
|user4|user3@somedomain.com|True|
|user5|user4@somedomain.com|True|
```

How do I get a list of enabled users that do **not** have expired passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, any string that is not empty (`[string]::Empty` or `''`) evaluates to `$true`, it's also worth noting that this happens because the [*boolean*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans) is in the LHS (*left-hand side*) of your comparison, hence PowerShell attempts type coercion on the RHS to match the same type as the LHS:

```bash
$true -eq 'False' # => True
[bool] 'False'    # => True
'False' -eq $true # => False
```

In this case the proper filtering would be:

```bash
Get-ADUser -Filter "enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties PasswordExpired |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PasswordExpired } |
        Select-Object -First 10
```

You can also use this filter instead of [`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.2#long-description) if you like:

```bash
Where-Object { $_.PasswordExpired -eq $false }
```